# How do I refresh project dependencies using Buildship in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Eclipse Mars was recently released and I felt like trying it out. It listed tighter integration with Gradle as one of its features via [Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship/downloads).

With Luna I was using [Gradle Integration for Eclipse (4.4)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44#.VB_gPGOMl40) and I found this a lot easier to work with for what I was trying to do; I could add a Gradle "nature" to an existing project without needing to remove the project and re-import it as I did with Buildship, and it automatically put all dependencies that I declared in `build.gradle` within the project's classpath.

With Buildship, I didn't see any option to configure an existing project as a Gradle project and I couldn't find a way to make it include the dependencies I specified in the build script within the project's classpath.

I tried installing the original plugin (GIfE 4.4) for Eclipse Mars and after restarting Eclipse it automatically did all that for me again. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to do this all through Buildship alone because right now, although it all works, it's quite a funny setup. My project's dropdown menu looks like this:

[image]

Apart from looking a bit odd it is actually quite a nice setup, since it combines the automatic dependency management of GIfE with the ability to run Gradle tasks directly from Eclipse that Buildship provides.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Updating the dependencies that eclipse sees should then be as simple as:

```
right click on project -> gradle -> refresh all
```

**Update in buildship 1.0.16**

<s>Currently you need to jump through the delete-and-import hoop the first time you use an existing gradle project with buildship.</s> You can now use the Add Gradle Nature option:

```
 right click on project -> configure -> Add Gradle Nature
```

> “Refresh Gradle Project” is now also shown when right-clicking on any .gradle file as well as in the context menu of the Gradle editor. [source](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-1-0-16-is-now-available/18056/1)

**See update below** <s>However sometimes you may find that when your project was imported, it didn't get the new Project and External Dependencies classpath</s> entry which you would normally be able to see in your `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`
If this is indeed missing, add the following to your project's `.classpath` file and all the gradle goodness should start working:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
```

> **Update in buildship 1.0.16**
>
> Gradle classpath container is restored if missing
>
> When converting an existing Eclipse Java project to Gradle, the Gradle classpath container was missing. It is now always added when a project is a Java project.

Comment: Anyone arriving here. This is the best answer, and should be included as the official doc.

Comment: Solved my issue too: closed my project, added that entry, and when i re-opened it the dependencies were there. Thanks a lot Paul! I'm on the latest version, 1.0.5, and a bit surprised such a big issue like this hasn't been fixed yet. Has anyone reported a bug for this yet?

Comment: as Nicolas Modrzyk allready mentioned, this should be included in the official doc!!!

Comment: The Buildship "Gradle Project" import wizard now asks to overwrite eclipse settings, which should fix the classpath issue I guess

Comment: incase for anyone, if you are not getting the project--> gradle link after doing the above step.  in build.gradle add apply plugin 'eclipse'; close the project in eclispe. run the gradle build from command line and then reopen the project in eclipse. Now the gradle link would be available on right click.

Comment: Depending on how you use it, **Git** relocates the project and breaks the refresh. Edit the gradle.prefs file in the root direction of the project and update the project_dir and connection_project_dir entries.

Comment: Does anyone know what `refresh all` actually does?  Gradle (STS) `refresh all` demolishes my project, and I only really want to refresh dependencies.  I might just have to use the Gradle Tasks tab and run things from there (or command line).

Answer (score 6):

Incase for anyone, if you are not getting the

> right click on project -> gradle

link after doing the steps mentioned in @PaulAdamson  answer. Try this.

1. In your build.gradle add `apply plugin 'eclipse';`
2. Close the project in eclispe.
3. Run the gradle build from command line and then reopen the project in eclipse.

   Now the gradle link should be available on right click.

Answer (score 4):

I agree Buildship is a bit of a disaster.  The documentation is extremely sparse with limited examples and minimal user guide.  You would think documenting the transition from Gradle Integration for Eclipse (4.4) would be a no-brainer but I guess not.  I also don't have a single clue how to use Buildship other than that I ran some tasks manually and it put **fully qualified paths** in my .classpath file.  That's ridiculous considering many projects are shared through change control systems.

Comment: You can avoid fully qualified paths for the most part using the eclipse pathVariables setting: 

`eclipse { pathVariables 'GRADLE_USER_HOME': gradle.gradleUserHomeDir }`

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseModel.html

This resolves most of the issues with our shared projects. As a manual step you have to also add the corresponding path to Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-classpath-variables.htm

Comment: Even when I agree with the claim, this is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no "Convert to Gradle project" implemented in Buildship. However, if you remove the project and reimport it using the Gradle import wizard you should see the same exact project with the proper nature and the classpath container.

On top of that, if you have a Gradle project in your workspace and update the dependencies in the build script, you can refresh the classpath container by right-clicking on the project and select `Gradle > Refresh projects`.

A similar problem you were facing was discussed in the Gradle forums: discuss.gradle.org/t/adding-dependencies-to-projects/10415.

We also have a bug dedicated for this feature request: bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465355. Please vote for it and share your thoughts there too.

Regarding to the documentation: It's true that we haven't provided an official documentation for the central Eclipse help system, but there are some resources explaining the current functionality:

- [The user documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/README.md)
- [A Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html)

Comment: With the current Buildship release, the option Gradle > Refresh projects is also available on the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already converted Java project to Gradle project but [RIGHT-CLICK]+Import (Then importing 'Existing Gradle Project') then your project should be of Gradle Nature.

If the project is of Gradle Nature then in .classpath file you will not see all the .jar dependencies as you see in normal java project, Instead you will see a single entry of:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
```

To refresh dependencies you should do following:

[RIGHT-CLICK] + Gradle + Refresh Gradle Project

This will fix all complication issues.