# How to use Buildship with existing Gradle projects

Tags: gradle, buildship

I've got several projects in my Eclipse workspace that use Gradle as their build system. Up to now, I'm running the Gradle commands from the command line.

I've installed Buildship in order to run Gradle tasks more conveniently from the "Gradle Tasks" view. But Buildship doesn't recognize the projects in my workspace as Gradle projects.

How to use Buildship with existing Gradle projects in the Eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 2):

The only way at the moment to make buildship pick up a project is to use the import wizard.

- delete your project from eclipse (doesn't remove your files)
- File -> import -> gradle -> gradle project

follow the wizard and your project should now show up as a gradle project. If you find you still don't have any dependencies in eclipse then it is probably picking up an existing non-buildship .project file, In which case the following post should help:

- [How do I refresh project dependencies using Buildship in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092934/how-do-i-refresh-project-dependencies-using-buildship-in-eclipse/31164637#31164637)

Comment: I have just installed buildship. When I try to Import I don't see any option for Gradle projects. Also I don't see it in the new project wizard. Is there something wrong with this plugin?