# How to have Buildship recognize existing projects in Eclipse Mars

Tags: gradle, maven-3, gradle-eclipse

I just converted my Maven project to a gradle project.  It was a multi project structure:

```
master-project
pom.xml
---->project1
-------->pom.xml
---->project2
-------->pom.xml
---->project3
-------->pom.xml
```

I ran a gradle init on it and have this structure now:

```
master-project
build.gradle
---->project1
-------->build.gradle
---->project2
-------->build.gradle
---->project3
-------->build.gradle
```

Everything builds fine, and I have been able to get some things done with that I couldn't figure out how to do with Maven, so that's great.  Next step was to integrate that into the IDE since the Maven Dependencies are gone since I have removed the pom.xml files.

However the project isn't recognized as a gradle project - and I am not sure how to change that?

In Eclipse Mars it's still recognized as a Maven build, not gradle....

[image]

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I reimported the projects which enabled the plugin for Eclipse.  Now I am having weird behavior.

The build works from the command line, however when attempting the same execution from within Eclipse, it fails trying to copy the file dependencies.

For example:
Couldn't copy dependency jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\user.m2\repository\jakarta-regexp\jakarta-regexp\1.4\jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar -> build\jfx\app\lib\jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar

I haven't changed the repo from maven yet - just changed the build scripts.  This is running from the master project.  So I am confused as to why the script would work from the commandline but not from within eclipse.

EDIT 2:  Turns out this behavior is also present when running from the command line when the --daemon flag is set.  Is there anyway to run the tasks without the daemon in Buildship?  Or perhaps a way to fix this issue when the --daemon flag is enabled?

Thanks.

Comment: I found this link which seems to point me in the correct direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092934/how-do-i-refresh-project-dependencies-using-buildship-in-eclipse

Comment: This I think was an issue with pathing, and is being fixed in the plug in

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the build was that there is a leak in the JDK when bundling the JRE with the native app.  This only happens when running with the --daemon flag (which all IDEs user).  Therefore until this is fixed you will need to run gradle --stop and then run the clean.

The plug in I am using is no longer running the native task when running with --daemon.