# Created a Gradle project in Eclipse but Refresh Dependencies is missing

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I just created a new Gradle project in Eclipse. As I understand it, the first thing to do now is to right click the project → `Gradle` → `Refresh Dependencies` - but I don't see that option. The only option I have is `Refresh Gradle project`.

What am I missing? I have the Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0 installed. Do I need something else?

My goal is to add a dependency. I think I have seen that, if I can perform this Refresh Dependencies command, I should be able to browse repositories in a GUI?

I have read several tutorials, e.g., https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html but it doesn't seem to relate to my problem.

Using Eclipse 2020-09.

Comment: _Refresh Gradle project_ does refresh the dependencies. Why do you think, there should be a menu item _Gradle > Refresh Dependencies_? Could you please link to the documentation that says so?

Comment: @howlger https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492729/1802826 https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908208/1802826 https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384813/1802826

Comment: @howlger https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976756/10028942

Comment: Better follow the vogella.com tutorial written by Eclipse developers than following Stack Overflow answers that might be outdated and wrong.